# Using a function to create a dataframe from a webscrape

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, web-scraping, python-requests

I have a function that takes in longitude, latitude, and UNIX time format. And outputs a single row dataframe with weather-related columns

```
['time', 'summary', 'icon', 'precipIntensity', 'precipProbability','precipType', 'temperature', 'apparentTemperature', 'dewPoint','humidity', 'pressure', 'windSpeed', 'windBearing', 'cloudCover','uvIndex', 'visibility']
```

---

```
 def get_weather(latitude,longitude,unix):
        url = "https://dark-sky.p.rapidapi.com/"+latitude+','+longitude+','+unix
        headers = {
        'x-rapidapi-key': "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxMYKEYxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        'x-rapidapi-host': "dark-sky.p.rapidapi.com"}
        response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers)
        data = response.json()
        weather = data['currently']
        weather = pd.DataFrame(weather, index=[0])
```

I would like to iterating through my dataset (10000 rows) and creating a new dataset with all the corresponding weather data for each row.

Comment: first create list with all rows (using `append()`) and later convert it to `DataFrame`

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, you have a dataset with information about latitude, longitude and unix and you want to iterate through that to create a new dataframe using the above function

Lets say your location dataframe is

```
location_df = pd.DataFrame([[10,10,5], [2,3,8], [9,9,10]],
columns=['lat','long','unix'])
```

To iterate through each row, use df.iterrows() and use append with ignore_index=True for auto-incrementing the index. In your case, suppose the function returns the weather dataframe, then:

```
precipitation_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['precipIntensity', 'precipProbability','temp']) # assume 3 values returned
for index, row in location_df.iterrows():
    latitude = row['lat']
    longitude = row['long']
    unix = row['unix']
    precipitation_df = precipitation_df.append(get_weather(latitude,longitude,unix), ignore_index=True)
```

Would love to know if anyone has a more efficient approach.